# How can I use regex in pattern for MongoDB `$jsonShema`?

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: "object",
    required: ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "destination"],
    properties: {
      firstName: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "First name is required!"
      },
      lastName: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "Last name is required!"
      },
      email: {
        bsonType: "string",
        pattern: "^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$",
        description: "Email is required"
      },
      destination: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "Destination is require!"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above `$jsonSchema`, I attempt to use pattern as part of the [schema specification](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#json-schema)

However, me existing ✉️ data fails validation inside of Compass.

This same pattern works just fine on client-side ReactJS form validation, so IK that the pattern itself is good.

However, something must be amiss with how we use this in `$jsonSchema`.

Comment: What data failed validation?

Comment: Also, your email regular expression is bogus.  There are all kinds of TLDs out there with more than 4 characters, like .museum.

Comment: Properly validating an email via regular expression is hard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/89211 - You have to decide what level of regular expression validation you're happy with.

Comment: Please provide example data you're validating which fails.

Comment: Mongodb uses PCRE regular expression, but it looks like your regex is simple enough not to cause a problem there.

Comment: I've noted your regular expression only accounts for upper case and not lower case. You can't set regex flags with JSON Schema (for example to ignore case)

Answer (score 0):

JSON Schema is encoded in JSON, and as such, strings need to be escaped.
This includes `\` which must become `\\`, so where in your regex you have `\.`, you need to escape it to become `\\.`.

Having said that, as I don't have examples of your JSON data (and the email) you're trying to valid, I'm assuming what you've said is correct regarding the regular expression being sufficient for you elsewhere.